# Pentaho Kettle, find replace in text file

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am trying to read a text file and replace all occurrence of a "search term" with "replace term" with regular expression and write the new file.

I am relatively new to pentaho kettle and not sure which transform or set of steps will suite best for this use case? Most transforms read data by rows or columns so I am not sure how to read a text file and do a find replace to work? Most transforms either file line by line or by fields.

Thanks for time and attention.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Input-> [Text file input](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Text+File+Input) : file type: Fixed, just one String field big enough

Step 2 - Transform -> [Replace in String](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Replace+in+String) : Use regexp: Y, Find: "search term", Replace: "replace term"

Step 3 - Output -> [Text file output](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Text+File+Output)

Not sure it's the best, but it works. Hope it helps.